# Webshims Lib - media queries for IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, polyfills

I'm trying to get media queries to work in IE8 using Webshims Lib. I've followed the setup instructions and loaded the default (all) polyfills, but it doesn't seem to work.

Am I still supposed to still explicitly include html5shiv? I thought Webshims Lib would take care of it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download `respond.js`, after adding these statements:

```
 <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media       queries -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <link href="css/bootstrap-ie8.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


 <![endif]-->
```